# Using word boundary instead of spaces in regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regex to get rid of the first and last word in a sentence, but it only works when I'm using spaces to match, but it doesn't work when I'm trying to use word boundary. Why is that?

**Using Spaces:**

```
$inputX = "she hates my guts";
preg_match("~ .+ ~i", $inputX, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => hates my )
```

**Using Word Boundary:**

```
$inputX = "she hates my guts";
preg_match("~\b.+\b~i", $inputX, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => she hates my guts )
```

Comment: The `.` is greedy so `.+?` but then the result is `she` because start of string is a boundary.

Comment: `\b` is before `she` and after `guts` as well.

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, but it's not `preg_match_all()` so only `she`.

Comment: why do you want to use word boundaries when you have a working regex with spaces? as @anubhava mentioned, `\b` will also match positions in the first and last word

Comment: By default, engines think of the beginning and end of string as a _NON-word_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the word boundaries:

```
 s h e   h a t e s   m y   g u t s 
^     ^ ^         ^ ^   ^ ^       ^
```

So your pattern matches like this:

```
 s h e   h a t e s   m y   g u t s 
^\_______________________________/^
|               |                 |
\b              .+                \b
```

If you want to get rid of the first and last word, I'd just replace these with an empty string, using the following pattern:

```
^\W*?\w+\s*|\s*\w+\W*$
```

Both `\W*` are there to account for possible punctuation (ie `she hates my guts.`) but you can remove them if they're not needed.

Comment: Hey, nice letter graphics!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the first and last word in a sentence, you can:

1. `explode()` on spaces
2. remove the first and last element with `array_slice()`
3. `implode()` back again

**Code**

```
$inputX = "she hates my guts";
$result = implode(" ", array_slice(explode(" ", $inputX), 1, -1));

var_dump($result);
```

**Output**

```
string(8) "hates my"
```